# Unable to save Plotly chart to a HTML file

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, brave

I tried to save a plotly chart as a HTML file but received error message `Access to the file was deniedThe file at file:///Users/Documents/notebooks/figure.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be preventing access.`

The html file didn't get saved. I'm using Brave browser, not sure are they related.

example code

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go
labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)])
fig.show()
pio.write_html(fig, file='figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved after switching browser to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this fig to HTML successfully and it works across all browsers I have tried. Admittedly, I haven't tried 'auto-open'.

```
fig.write_html("C:/???/???/Desktop/Port.html")
```